# How can I show the stock values of config, simple's stock (available sizes) on the catalog page?

Tags: magento-1.9, stock

I'm trying to figure out how to show the sizes of simple products in stock on a catalog front-end page. After getting the values I'd like to extend the catalog pages with a nice hover effect showing the available sizes for this specific product. Since this is a work in progress, please do not start about the module structure as this is a proof of concept.

So far I can show the label using the following code:

```
     $configurable = $_product->getTypeInstance();
     $childProducts = $_product->getUsedProducts($configurable);
     foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
     // You have a $child now
        echo $product->getAttributeText( $attribute->getLabel());
    }
    }
```

This would print the associated Attribute Label for this configurable product like: **Shoe Sizes:**

I'm able to display all the associated sizes:

```
    $attrs  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
foreach($attrs as $attr) {
if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
    $options    = $attr['values'];
   print_r($options);
    foreach($options as $option) {
       print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";

    }
}
```

This would print all configurable attribute values: **39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49**

But I'm struggling to just show the sizes that **are in stock**.
The idea is to only get something like:
**42 43 44**
Any help would be appreciated.

See example image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKh0s.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've written a possible solution in the meanwhile, however it's extremely poor written:

```
//TODO OPTIMIZE horrible code
$sizeslabels = array();
 $j = 0;
if ($_product->isConfigurable()) {
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
     $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
   .$simple->getValue();


     if($simple->getValue() != "0.0000"){
         $sizeslabels[] = preg_split("/\s+(?=\S*+$)/",$simple->getName());
         $j = $j + 1;
     }


 }



   for ($i = 0; $i < $j; ++$i) {


    $c=0;
    foreach($sizeslabels[$i] as $key=>$value){
        $c++;
        if($key == 1){
        echo $value;
        if($i<$j-1) echo ",";
        }

    }




    }
}
```

This will output something similar to: XS,S,M,L.